# Most efficient Algorithm to find objects with most objects near it in 500 feet

Tags: python, algorithm

I want to find out what would be most efficient algorithm to find tree with most number of neighboring trees (say within 500 feet radius of it).  We can use dataset  from https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Environment/2015-Street-Tree-Census-Tree-Data/pi5s-9p35 for this.  I understand Python better but any other language or just pseudo code will be fine too!

In above dataset (export in CSV from above link), columns of interest are tree_id, x_sp and y_sp (they are x coordinate and y coordinate of tree).

No geospatial or special libraries please as this is algorithm how to question.

Comment: Actually, this question probably could be better asked in another Stack Exchange site, like Computer Science.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say which would be the most efficient, but one data structure you might use would be the KD-Tree: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree (I think there is a python example in this article).